# SQL Query for IBM DB2 Database - Recursive Query?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, db2, ibm-midrange

Hello All and thank you for taking the time to review my question!

I'm a novice first and foremost - figuring this out and self-teaching as I go (so if I mix term please let me know or ask clarification).

I am attempting to query a database at work that is on a IBM DB2 Driver. I am using Microsoft Access with Pass-Through to run the query through an ODBC connection to database.

**The problem:** I am attempting to identify customer records that have services that have expired, but these same customer records may have additional services that are NOT expired. I need to know which customers have expired services, and NO services scheduled to come online.

This is what I've got so far and it's functional to get my HALF of the problem solved.

```
SELECT
    MAIN.LOB,
    MAIN.CC,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER#,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER_NAME,
    X4_1.QUANTITY,
    X4_1.SERVICEID, -- this is the field in which contains customer services
    X4_1.ROUTE,
    X3."SERVICE START",
    X3."SERVICE END", -- this field determines if the service is expired
    T1."SALES NAME",
    T2."SALES ID"

FROM "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE1 as X3
-- CONCAT(MAIN.CC, MAIN.CUSTOMER#) is to create a unique ID for customers
    LEFT JOIN "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE2 AS T2 ON CONCAT(X3.CC, X3.CUSTOMER#) = CONCAT(T2.CC, T2.CUSTOMER#)
    LEFT JOIN "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE3 AS T1 ON T1.EMPID = T2.EMPID
    LEFT JOIN "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE4 AS X4_1 ON CONCAT(X3.CC, X3.CUSTOMER#) = CONCAT(X4_1.CC, X4_1.CUSTOMER#)
    LEFT JOIN  "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE5 AS MAIN ON CONCAT(MAIN.CC, MAIN.CUSTOMER#) = CONCAT(X3.CC, X3.CUSTOMER#)

WHERE
    MAIN.CUS#ID IN ('C', 'R')
    AND X4_1.SERVICEID IS NOT NULL
    AND X4_1.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL
    AND (
            -- return any services with an expiration date that has passed or set to pass within 15 days           
            X3.SVENDDATE <= CURRENT_DATE + (15 DAYS)
        )

    AND X4_1.ROUTE NOT LIKE '%@%'
    AND X4_1.ROUTE NOT LIKE '%$%'
    AND X4_1.ROUTE IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTR(X4_1.ROUTE, 2, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
    AND (MAIN.CANDAT < MAIN.STRDAT OR MAIN.DATE_SUSPENDED < MAIN.DATE_RESTARTED)

Group By
    MAIN.LOB,
    MAIN.CC,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER#,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER_NAME,
    X4_1.QUANTITY,
    X4_1.SERVICEID,
    X4_1.ROUTE,
    X3."SERVICE START",
    X3."SERVICE END",
    T1."SALES NAME",
    T2."SALES ID"

LIMIT 100
```

**GOAL:** I need to now rerun a similar query that will search the database for ONLY the customers appearing in the 1st query (for the sake of speed/optimization), but identify the services that have an end date of 01/01/9999 or greater.

`X3.SVENDDATE >= DATE('9999-01-01')`

**NON-Working Attempts:** I tried to use a union in the query but this DB2 does not allow UNION - or maybe its because of how I am trying to query using Access? I honestly don't know.

**The ideal end results:** 1 table that has customer records that contain my various selected fields and any associated records that have either a expired/soon to expire service or that same customer but with services set to expire 01/01/9999 or later.

There should NOT be any customers records that have a non-expired/soon to expire service.

Once I get the query working the plan is to then set up a connection with an excel file and macro (i've already got all that set up) to then allow this to be ran directly from the excel file and refresh.

I COULD just run 2 separate queries to then cross reference them, but the results of the 2nd Query (all services with end date >= 01/01/9999) is MASSIVE (talking hours to run), which is why I need to limit that query by only using customers identified by the first query.

Comment: Can help to provide sample raw data and desired output. Might find NOT IN(SELECT ...) syntax useful.

Answer (score 0):

identify customer records that have expired services, and NO services scheduled to come online:

```
SELECT
    MAIN.LOB,
    MAIN.CC,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER#,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER_NAME,
    X4_1.QUANTITY,
    X4_1.SERVICEID, -- this is the field in which contains customer services
    X4_1.ROUTE,
    X3."SERVICE START",
    X3."SERVICE END", -- this field determines if the service is expired
    T1."SALES NAME",
    T2."SALES ID"

FROM "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE1 as X3
-- CONCAT(MAIN.CC, MAIN.CUSTOMER#) is to create a unique ID for customers
    LEFT JOIN "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE2 AS T2 ON CONCAT(X3.CC, X3.CUSTOMER#) = CONCAT(T2.CC, T2.CUSTOMER#)
    LEFT JOIN "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE3 AS T1 ON T1.EMPID = T2.EMPID
    LEFT JOIN "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE4 AS X4_1 ON CONCAT(X3.CC, X3.CUSTOMER#) = CONCAT(X4_1.CC, X4_1.CUSTOMER#)
    LEFT JOIN  "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE5 AS MAIN ON CONCAT(MAIN.CC, MAIN.CUSTOMER#) = CONCAT(X3.CC, X3.CUSTOMER#)

WHERE
    MAIN.CUS#ID IN ('C', 'R')
    AND X4_1.SERVICEID IS NOT NULL
    AND X4_1.QUANTITY IS NOT NULL
    AND (
            -- return any services with an expiration date that has passed or set to pass within 15 days           
            X3.SVENDDATE <= CURRENT_DATE + (15 DAYS)
        )

    AND X4_1.ROUTE NOT LIKE '%@%'
    AND X4_1.ROUTE NOT LIKE '%$%'
    AND X4_1.ROUTE IS NOT NULL
    AND SUBSTR(X4_1.ROUTE, 2, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
    AND (MAIN.CANDAT < MAIN.STRDAT OR MAIN.DATE_SUSPENDED < MAIN.DATE_RESTARTED)

Group By
    MAIN.LOB,
    MAIN.CC,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER#,
    MAIN.CUSTOMER_NAME,
    X4_1.QUANTITY,
    X4_1.SERVICEID,
    X4_1.ROUTE,
    X3."SERVICE START",
    X3."SERVICE END",
    T1."SALES NAME",
    T2."SALES ID"

HAVING
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM "SCHEMA.LIB".FILE1 AS X3_1
        WHERE X3_1.CC = X3.CC
        AND X3_1.CUSTOMER# = X3.CUSTOMER#
        AND X3_1.SVENDDATE >= DATE('9999-01-01')
    )
```

This query will first identify all customers who have services that have expired or are set to expire within 15 days. It will then filter out any customers who have any services that are scheduled to come online after 01/01/9999. The final result will be a list of customers who have expired services, and NO services scheduled to come online.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest - I don't know SQL well enough to freely read someone else's code and somehow modify it?

But for general reasons - maybe it will be easier to split the query into several using WITH?

An example from personal practice:

```
with ClientType as
  (select C4CTP,
          cast (case
                  when C4CBQ = 'C' and C4IND = 'N' and C4CIGR <> '12' then 'U'
                  else 'F'
                end as char(1)) CLTP
     from C4PF
   where ((C4IND = 'Y' and C4CBQ in ('B', 'C', 'N'))
      or  (C4IND = 'N' and C4CBQ = 'C')))
select GFCUS,
       GFCLC,
       GFCPNC,
       GFCRF,
       BGDTBR,
       CLTP,
       cast (case
               when GFDCC > 0 or GFDEL = 'Y' then 'X'
               when GFCOD >= :WDate then 'N'
               else '1'
             end as char(1))
from GFPF
join ClientType on (C4CTP) = (GFCTP)
join BGPF on (BGCUS, BGCLC) = (GFCUS, GFCLC)
where (GFDLM >= :WDate or GFCOD >= :WDate or GFDCC >= :WDate);
```

There is a ClientType subquery that selects the given types of clients and returns the type in the CLTP field. The main query uses a JOIN to this subquery and thus selects only those clients whose type is F or U.

Maybe in your case you can go the same way?